# Why my texture lines show up distorted and not completely straight at few parts?

Tags: texturing

i am trying to get clean straight UV map lines for an object with texture without trilling or distortion. 
 as you can see in the picture , a few lines are nice and clean , some others are distorted and a bit trilled and not completely straight .
it gives a bit of a non professional look. ok i am not professional , but still...i  want things to work out at it's best where i can. 
 all lines should be nice and straight , and not just a few of them . 
the UV map that i have used is the basic unwrap. nothing special . 
 i like this result , except for the distortion problem. 
 but how can i fix the distorted lines ?
first of all , they should have never been distorted since i never changed something in the UV map  to get them distorted at the lines. 
 we can see most of the lines are distorted at one side and the other side they are nice and straight. 
 how do i get them nice and straight at both sides ?
i don't want to change the arrangement of how the lines are running , just want to get the distortion out of the lines.
i would think something is wrong with the UV map , but it is the basic UV map , nothing should be wrong with it , 
anyone ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer by myself by accident , 
it was quite obvious afterwards , 
all i had to do is to increase the amount of subdivisions , 
all the lines are perfect smooth and straight now ! no more distortion. 
it's beautiful.

Answer (score 3):

your UV sphere has uneven faces but the unwraping made them even, distorting the texture

[image]

Comment: that is a good explanation, but i forgot to ask for a solution , anyway i found the answer already.